# How do I remove firefox addons which are not shown on addons list?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

When I clicked on `Add to Firefox` plugin from `https://addons.mozilla.org`  ,
It is not showing on **addons manager**. I have search on `extension` as well as on `apperance`
But when I click again on that same button 'Add to Firefox` it is showing error:

```
    Firefox could not install the search plugin from '................. ' 
because an engine with the same name already exists.
```

So that **add-on** exists in my browser. How do I remove it?
I am using firefox 28.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some steps for removing the extension. Go to AppData folder in your user folder. Then, Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\ After this, there will most likely be one profile. Open this and then the extensions folder. Try to find the extension and delete it. The names are not what you are used to, so the task can be rather hard... Hope this helps!

Comment: `about:addons` leads you to **Add-ons Manager** in Firefox. OP has already stated that the add-on there.

Comment: @rsya-studio Sorry, I had not realized that he had said, "It is not showing on addons manager." In response then, I should have said to go to AppData folder in your user folder. Then, Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\ After this, there will most likely be one profile. Open this and then the extensions folder. Try to find the extension and delete it. The names are not what you are used to, so the task can be rather hard... Hope this helps!

Comment: OK, would be nice if you edited your answer so I can change my vote :)

Comment: @rsya-studio, I have edited my answer...